# How does ES6 class instance variable work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I have the following code which is working as expected:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

let result = null;
class MyData extends Component {
  _getData = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        result = items.find(
          item => item.id === 'abcd'
        );
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getData();
  }

  render() {
    return result ? <span>hello</span> : null;
  }
}
```

When I try to move `result` as an instance variable of the class as follows, it always remains **null** in the `render()` method. Though the assignment is working correctly post fetch:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyData extends Component {
  result = null;
  _getData = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.result = items.find(
          item => item.id === 'abcd'
        );
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getData();
  }

  render() {
    return this.result ? <span>hello</span> : null;
  }
}
```

Can someone explain me what is the expected usage here. And how things have changed from ES6 onwards.

Comment: `=>` functions don't do `this` the way that regular functions do, so you've got no reference to the instance in the `_getData` function.

Comment: The expected usage in React is that you would store the data in the *state* which would trigger a rerender.

Comment: @Pointy should `this` be defined lexically as the instance there? It seems like this is an issue of async behavior.

Comment: No, calling a `=>` function does not result in a `this` value being bound during the function call under any circumstances.

Comment: "I have the following code which is working as expected:

"-> What is expected? it remains null in first case too https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-microservice-ozgrr

Comment: Your examples just don't work, the first example is null either.

Comment: @Pointy this is ES6 class properties syntax, so calling `=>` class property function results in `this` being the class instance inside the function

Comment: @Max ah because instance properties are treated as being initialized in the constructor, which is a "normal" function and has the `this` value bound to the new instance. That makes sense, though it's part of why instance property syntax really makes me upset. It's a "me" problem of course.

Comment: @Pointy it has nothing to do with bindings though in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both examples just don't work, **the reason is that `componentDidMount` lifecycle fires after `render` lifecycle**.

Because you don't cause re-render (with `setState`) in any phase, **nothing will cause an additional render** to read the updated value of `result`.

[image]

Therefore, the next example will always render `No Result`

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

let result = null;

class App extends Component {
  thisResult = null;
  setResult = () => {
    result = 10;
    this.thisResult = 10;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setResult();
  }

  render = () => {
    return <div>{result || this.thisResult ? 'Result' : 'No Result'}</div>;
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit flamboyant-snowflake-u4s6x]

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing null is because the state is not being updated in the code example you posted. The component mounts and `this.result` is null. But when the `_getData` method is called and the response comes back, the component is not being rendered.

You should be storing this data in your state, as React relies on the state changes to know when it should re-render the component. Try something like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyData extends Component {
  state = {
    result: null
  }
  _getData = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          result: items.find(
            item => item.id === 'abcd'
          )
        })
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getData();
  }

  render() {
    const { result } = this.state
    return result ? <span>hello</span> : null;
  }
}
```

You can learn more about rendering, state, and component lifecycles here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class

**Edit:** If you want to experiment with the new react hooks api, you could convert your component to look like the folllowing:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MyData = ({ ...props }) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);

  const getData = () => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const result = items.find(item => item.id === 'abcd');

        setResult(result);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return result ? <span>hello</span> : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main thing you're missing is state.  Keep in mind that these Components you are extending are React Component classes which have a very specific life cycle.  Look into component life cycle for more info.  This will work as expected with the following refactor:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyData extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {result:  null};
    }

    _getData = () => {
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            let resp = data.items.find(
                item => item.id === 'abcd'
            );

            this.setState({ result: resp });
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this._getData();
    }

    render() {
       return this.state.result ? <span>hello</span> : null;
    }
 }
```